# read TXT or list whole TXT on same folder using html

Tags: html, iframe, text

**Problem** : Working on project to make an html code to read or list all text files on the same directory i managed to read text but i have to give it name.
So what i need is to make html code to read all text files on same folder like make it search for all the text and display them or say what is the name of each text can u help or suppot.

thanks to support me how to do such thing

What i did :

<iframe src="read.txt" frameborder="0" height="400"

What i need :

<iframe src="all text files .txt" frameborder="0" height="400"

Comment: list all txt files

Answer (score 1):

Well, you cannot achieve that using HTML. HTML does not support manipulating files (searching for files, listing all files in current directory, etc.), other than the basic `src="yourfilename"`.

To achieve what you want, you need some server-side coding (e.g. a small PHP program can easily do that for you).

Comment: hmm but html cannot? can i add php code on html but why html cannot at least list names it can read why listing is hard?

Comment: can i add java script to html to so file manipulating of source listing

Comment: Well, even Javascript cannot manipulate files as it is a client-side scripting language (runs on the user's computer, not on the server where the website resides). This is the case because of security purposes. You need a server-side scripting language (e.g. PHP or C#) for file manipulation.

Comment: And yes, you can insert PHP into your HTML code, but the page will need to have the extension .php instead of .html

Comment: all will be server side then with html i cannot even del somthing all i can do read txt can i unzip with html?

Comment: Unzipping with HTML? You're literally asking if you can go to the moon with a motorcycle. HTML is just a **markup language**, that is, a language that is made to display content on a page. It has no logic, no functions, just displaying content.

Comment: He is right, what you need is a server side function that returns all the content of those files as a JSON or XML and call that API function from JavaScript and then render the result in html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<a_unzip> file.zip </a>` for a quick and easy fix just make sure to rezip the file using `<a_ziper>file.zip</a.zipback>`or you might get an infinite zippyleak.

Comment: Then you can ride a space ship using `<spaceship></spaceship>` tag and walk on the moon